# Laravel: can't pass variable to the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a couple of blade pages using inheritance and I am trying to show the list of a product in one page. However when the object is passed to the view something is going wrong and it's crashing the app.

The error I am getting is `Undefined variable: batteries`.

With `isset($batteries)` I tested that indeed the variable is not getting to the view.

Here is the code:

```
/* controller */

class HomeController extends \BaseController {

    public function index() {
        $view = View::make('home.index')->render();
        return Response::json(['view' => $view]);
    }

    public function main() {
        $batteries = Battery::all();
        $view = View::make('home.main', compact('batteries'))->render();
        return Response::json(['view' => $view]);
    }

}
```

Views:

```
<!-- home/index.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@include('home.main')

@stop

<!-- home/main.blade.php -->
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach ($batteries as $battery)
        <li class="list-group-item">$battery->name</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

What is wrong? Why is the variable undefined?

**Edit**

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('home.index');
});

Route::group(['before' => 'ajax'], function() {
    Route::get('/home/main', ['as' => 'home.main', 'uses' => 'HomeController@main']);
});
```

Comment: The route pointing to the `index()` method will cause this error, as no $batteries variable is sent to the view. But without your route we do not know what i going on...

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to return by `return Response::json(['view' => $view]);`. are you trying to return the json or the html view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is for `index` method where you display `home.index` This file include `home.main` and in this file you use `$batteries` variable.

You should not include `home.main` template here or add extra checking if `$batteries` are set:

```
@if (isset($batteries))
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach ($batteries as $battery)
        <li class="list-group-item">{{{ $battery->name }}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

To display name of $battery, you should also use `{{{ $battery->name }}}` and not just `$battery->name`

**EDIT**

The problem is your route, it should be to use your controller method:

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
```

and now you can change your `index` method into:

```
$batteries = Battery::all();
$view = View::make('home.main', compact('batteries'))->render();
return Response::json(['view' => $view]);
```

Comment: thanks you that's it. Except that I should change the type of response in the `index` method. I should respond with a `return View::make()` rather than with a json response, because the root page is being called with a regular get request, rather than with ajax, which is what I am using for my whole page.

Comment: @dabadaba Of course, that's up to you what type of response you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

You don't send a `$batteries` variable from your `index` method, so of course there won't be one. The `main` method will not run just because you include the `main.blade.php` view.

You need to do the same thing in your `index` method as in your `main` method.

```
public function index() {
    $batteries = Battery::all();
    $view = View::make('home.index', compact('batteries'))->render();
    return Response::json(['view' => $view]);
}
```

Comment: I tried that too and I was still getting the `undefined batteries` error. I will edit my post with my routes.